# Stuck in setting values to arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've been reading about arrays in the PHP manual website, but it's very confusing!

However, I managed to start something off:

```
$refarray = array("Test", "Test2");
//$online[];
//$names[];

foreach($refarray as $refarr)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.xfire.com/xml/$refarr/status");
    //$online = $xml->status;
    //$names = $xml->nickname;
}
```

I just can't figure out how to store 2 values "status" and "nickname" in arrays so I can use them later on here:

```
//foreach($online as $on) Loop through the original array and echo its values "status" and "nickname"
//{
   //   echo $online[$on];
   //   echo $names[$
//}
```

Comment: Double quote your strings for interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append a row to the `$info` array each time through the loop.

```
$info = array();
foreach ($refarray as $refarr) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.xfire.com/xml/$refarr/status");
    $info[] = array('status' => $xml->status, 'nickname' => $xml->nickname);
}

foreach ($info as $i) {
    echo 'Status: ' . $i['status'] . ' | Nickname: ' . $i['nickname'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time. I managed to get something working, but the problem is that its only showing the last items in the array:  `$refarray = array("Test", "Test2");

foreach($refarray as $refarr)
{
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.xfire.com/xml/$refarr/status");

 $info = array(array('status' => $xml->status, 'nickname' => $xml->nickname));
}


foreach ($info as $i) {
    echo 'Status: ' . $i['status'] . ' | Nickname: ' . $i['nickname'] . '<br>';
}` It only shows info about "Test2", I want it to show info of both items in the "refarray" array.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You're assigning the same variable each time through the loop, so at the end it just contains the last result. You need to push a new element onto the array each time.